# awk won't return the the required output

Tags: ubuntu, awk

I have a file, which has on line 16 Country and Currency (learning awk):

```
bartek@Lenovo-LAB:~/Desktop/bash_lessons/04/demos/Module4_Demo_Files$ sed -n '16p' currencies.csv 
FIJI,Fiji Dollar
```

when I use awk to extract some values I don't get expected output:

```
bartek@Lenovo-LAB:~/Desktop/bash_lessons/04/demos/Module4_Demo_Files$ awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1; FS=","} /fiji/ { print NR,"-",$0 }' currencies.csv 
bartek@Lenovo-LAB:~/Desktop/bash_lessons/04/demos/Module4_Demo_Files$
```

why it doesn't return **16 - FIJI,Fiji Dollar**?

Comment: You're possibly not using GNU `awk` (which is the only `awk` I know has a special `IGNORECASE` variable).

Comment: i just use the one bundled with latest Ubuntu, what would be a workaround if IGNORECASE is not supported, but you still want to achieve the same?

Comment: So can we confirm if it is GNU awk or not? ```awk --version```

Comment: apologies, can't run --version but man shows mawk when I call man awk

Comment: It looks like recent versions of Ubuntu are shipping `mawk` by default. You should be able to confirm this by running `awk -W version`.

Comment: Try with `awk 'tolower($0)~"fiji"{ ... }'`. Or, better, learn perl instead of awk ;-)

Comment: with respect to `when I pipe it to awk...` - you don't need sed when you're using awk. `sed -n 16p | awk '{whatever}'` = `awk 'NR==16{whatever}'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IGNORECASE` variable is a special variable that affects case sensitivity in regular expressions and string operations (also in field splitting if `FS` is a regular expression, but see the GNU `awk` manual on your system for details), but only for GNU `awk`.  No other `awk` has this variable.

From what you are saying [in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/631537/awk-wont-return-the-the-required-output?noredirect=1#comment1181925_631537), it seems as if your default `awk` is `mawk`, not GNU `awk`.

To do a case insensitive regular expression match in a non-GNU `awk`, simply convert the string to either lower or upper case using `tolower()` or `toupper()`, and then use an all lowercase or uppercase regular expression:

```
awk -F , 'tolower($0) ~ /fiji/ { print NR, "-", $0 }' currencies.csv
```

```
awk -F , 'toupper($0) ~ /FIJI/ { print NR, "-", $0 }' currencies.csv
```

You could also use `grep` for the task that you're doing here:

```
grep -n -i 'fiji' currencies.csv
```

The output would have a *slightly* different format, with each line prefixed by `n:`, where `n` is the line number from the original file. You could obviously fix that by passing the output through `sed 's/:/ - /'`.

Comment: Minor point: busybox awk seems to have `IGNORECASE`. It may also be worth mentioning the case of a non-constant ERE token, which requires something along the lines of `tolower($0) ~ tolower(ere)` to mimic case-insensitive matching.

Comment: s/and string operations/and non-array-index string operations/. It applies for a direct comparison or an `index()` match but it doesn't apply for a hash lookup for example. Try `echo 'foo' | awk -v IGNORECASE=1 '$0 == "FOO"` vs `echo 'foo' | awk -v IGNORECASE=1 'BEGIN{x["FOO"]} $0 in x'`